# Why is 'application' not working in a subroute in Ember?

Tags: ember.js, routes, router

I'm developing an Ember frontend which has to handle an 'application' resource.
My router looks like this:

```
this.route('applications', function() {
   this.route('application', { path: ':application_id'}
   );
);
```

I get the following error:

Assertion Failed: 'application' cannot be used as a route name.

This seems to conflict with 'application' route of the Ember application.

Changing the route name from 'applications/application' to 'applications/app' works, but this is not very elegant.

Does anybody know if/why a subroute can never be '.../application/...'?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would imagine that this had to do with the fact that `application` is the top level route of the entire application in EmberJS. It is a reserved keyword in the framework and can't be used for anything other than its purpose that has been set out by EmberJS.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I ended up naming the route 'app' and used the path attribute to have the URL show 'application'.